# Why were two songs cut in the 2001 musical Roméo et Juliette: de la Haine à l'Amour?

Tags: musical

I enjoyed the DVD recording of the 2001 French musical *Roméo et Juliette: de la Haine à l'Amour* ([IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0410532/)). When I later looked for its *Original Recordings* album, I noticed two additional songs *La folie* and *Pourquoi* that I completely had no impression about. They did not appear in the video.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rom%C3%A9o_et_Juliette_(musical)),

> "La folie" and "Pourquoi" were sung until Jun. 27, 2001

This is about as far as online searching goes. I'm still curious about the reasoning behind the cut of these two songs.

---

P.S. I found in the end credits ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRZyymva6xo&t=8970s)) that the video was produced in July 2001 (Juillet 2001), which was just past the time the two songs were cut. Presumably the video was not recorded from the original January premiere.

Comment: Release runtime of 2:20, it was probably cut for time.

Comment: @Tetsujin It doesn't seem compelling that such a brief time is worth the omission of two masterpieces. Any sources to back that claim up?